# JFugue: Get music string duration

Tags: jfugue

Given the music string `Aq Aq Bi Bi Ci Ci` is there an object in JFugue that can retrieve its duration (as a double or as a string)?

For example:

```
double musicStringDuration = new DurationMapper().getDoubleMSDuration("Aq Aq Bi Bi Ci Ci");
System.out.println(musicStringDuration); \\ prints 1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFugue's `org.jfugue.tools` package contains several tools, including one that will tell you the total duration of a each voice (whether those voices is written as Staccato Strings like you have, or as MIDI channels for music you import, or anything else that JFugue can parse - and it's easy to write new parsers). `ComputeDurationForEachTrackTool` (and another tool, `GetInstrumentsUsedTool`) are `ParserListener`s, and there is a common pattern in JFugue to use a Parser Listener:

```
*Some*Parser parser = new *Some*Parser();
*Another*ParserListener listener = new *Another*ParserListener();
parser.addParserListener(listener);
parser.parse(*whatever the parser takes*);
*Type* *value* = listener.*method*();
```

Specifically for your case, you would have:

```
StaccatoParser parser = new StaccatoParser();
ComputeDurationForEachTrackTool tool = new ComputeDurationForEachTrackTool();
parser.addParserListener(tool);
parser.parse("Aq Aq Bi Bi Ci Ci");
double[] durationsOfEachVoice = tool.getDurations();
```

While this is longer than the statement you suggested in your question, this is immensely powerful, as it provides a means to connect *any* parser to *any* parser listener or tool.

You would find 1.0 in `durationsOfEachVoice[0]`.

Actually, you'll find 2.0 in there, which is unexpected. But I just ran a test on it, and it's returning 0.5 for a quarter note and 0.25 for an eighth note. Sounds like a fix for JFugue version 6! In the meantime, please divide by 2.0 and accept my apologies.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Anyway i might need to obtain the duration of a staccato string that contains also chords, like "C#mini C#mini C#mini C#mini C#mini C#mini C#mini C#mini". For this case i am obtaining 0.0 inside durationsOfEachVoice[0]. Is there a different parser for chords?

Comment: Ideally, that *should* work, and the fact that it isn't working is a bug. But since it's using the Staccato parser, which clearly knows how to find durations for a chord, I'm not sure why this would be a bug. Maybe I wrote it assuming notes only. I'll have to figure that out. Thanks for letting me know!